# Java NullPointerException when trying to consume a Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, nullpointerexception

I have a Java Web Application with a Web Service and a Java Application that tries to consume that Web Service. The Web Service contains an operation named `update` and i call this operation from the Java Application as:

```
private static Boolean update(webservice.BsInfo profile)
{
    webservice.MyWs_Service service = new webservice.MyWs_Service();
    webservice.MyWs port = service.getMyWsPort();
    return port.update(profile);
}
```

Here `BsInfo` is a class defined in the Web Application, and `webservice` is the package that contains this class in the Web Application. When i am trying to run the Java Application (with the Web App deployed of course) i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at $Proxy30.update(Unknown Source)
at Assignment1.BaseStationProfile.update(BaseStationProfile.java:70)
at Assignment1.BaseStationProfile.run(BaseStationProfile.java:23)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

where line 70 is `return port.update(profile);`.

What could be possibly wrong here so that the connection to the Web Service doesn't succeed?

Comment: have you tried calling the same web service with soap ui may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide enough information.
It could be that:
1) `profile` is `null`
2) `port` is `null`
3) the web service `returns` null

For case (1) and (2) it is not easy to help you without putting more code.

For case (3) you can use wireshark to see what the web service returns to pin point if it is a problem in server or client handling.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me wireshark(ethereal) exists!!

Comment: I am getting below error, are they similar or its totally different issue :

`03-08-2015 12:32:00,358 SEVERE [com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1] (pool-2183-thread-1) SAAJ0304: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message
03-08-2015 12:32:00,537 ERROR [stderr] (pool-2183-thread-1) javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: org.switchyard.HandlerException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @eestein how have u used wireshark to detect the null pointer error?

Comment: @nikos how have u used wireshark to detect the null pointer error?

Comment: @Tito it's so long ago I don't even remember the problem... but to find out how to use wireshark you can check their website https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseMainWindowSection.html